# do while not execution, terminates unexpectedly

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, logic

I have the following code, i wanted to terminate the while loop if any key except `1 & 2` is press. but only `do` executes once. and not `while`. why my `while condition` is always false. please guide:

```
char a;

do
{
    printf("To Enter the Employee sales press 1 \n");
    printf("To Add more items press 2 \n ");
    printf("Press any key to Terminate \n\n");  

        scanf("%c", &a);
    if ( a == '1' )
    {
        printf("1 is presed ");
    }
    else if(a == '2')
    {
        int c;

        printf("entre Value:");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        printf("\n");
        addItem( &myArray, &size, c );
        printitems(myArray, size);   
    }
}while(a == '1' || a == '2');
```

**Edit** So sorry, it was in single qout. i forgot to put the latest code. Even with qoutes it does not run while.

Comment: a == '1'... (in single quotes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space before your `%c` in `scanf()`:

```
scanf(" %c", &a);
```

You're reading the first character that's entered and leaving one on the buffer. So if you enter:

`'1'` you're really getting two characters, first `'1'` then a `'\n'` (a "1" then a new line character, that happens when you hit enter). So it first stores `'1'` into `a`, then the second time it will read the remaining newline character into `a`, (it will apear to "skip" asking you for input). Since `'\n'` is not equal to `'1'` or `'2'` so it correctly exits.

Adding the space before the `%c` tells `scanf()` to ignore any white space left on the buffer (and new line characters count as white space)

Comment: Could not image in my wildest dreams about this. So much for ur time. i'm, feeling stupid. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared 'a' as type char. and your while condition is

---

while(a == 1 || a == 2);

---

It should be

---

while(a == '1' || a == '2');

Comment: check that your addItem and printitems works perfectly.
Without using those 2 function it works perfectly